# Seemingly random WebRTC ICE connection failure when connecting to same machine

Tags: webrtc

I have an app which creates two instances of RTCPeerConnection (within the same JS context) which attempt to connect to each other. While I'm developing, I reload the page often, maybe several times per minute. About 10% of the time, WebRTC will fail to progress to the 'iceConnectionState == "connected"' stage. This failure occurs even when I pass no STUN/TURN servers to `createPeer()`.

I primarily use Chrome (OSX, currently version 81.0.4044.138). I have never been able to reproduce this on Firefox.

I have captured nearly-identical dumps of the [success](https://pastebin.com/raw/fJy0tn8H) and [failure](https://pastebin.com/raw/e759dwdh) cases using chrome://webrtc-internals.

I have spent many hours on this and haven't found any clue as to why this might be failing. Is it just some kind of temporary local network outage? Is there anything I can do within the code to have a 100% local connection rate?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar flakiness because of mDNS candidates. Try disabling `#enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns` in chrome://flags and see if that helps!

After that I would grab a `tcpdump` and confirm you see ICE traffic flowing each way.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'm giving that a shot now. If you don't hear back, it probably worked!